# How to change css of control in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the css of one td through jquery. Please help on this. This is not working for me
$("#tdTopMenu").css({ "backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white" });

aspx code:

```
 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td id = "tdTopMenu" runat = "server" style="width: 100%" class="hideColumn">
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#jMenu").jMenu({
                ulWidth: '150',
                effects: {
                    effectSpeedOpen: 300,
                    effectTypeClose: 'slide'
                },
                animatedText: false
            });

            $("#tdTopMenu").css({ "backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white" });    
        });

      </script>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/ByhgD/

Comment: did u check if it has anything to do with class="hideColumn" which you have added in yoru td tag?

Comment: Thank you Nitin... its working now... In hide column i was mentioned display none... now changed that to block in jquery... its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#<%=tdTopMenu.ClientID%>").css({ "backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white" });
```

ASP.NET Web Form changes the IDs when they are rendered to HTML so you need to retrieve the client-side id, rather than using the server ID.

Alternatively you can add ClientIdMode="Static" to tdTopMenu.

Answer (score 1):

```
id != tdTopMenu
```

delete runat = "server" on element `<td>` and re try

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $("#"<%=tdTopMenu.ClientID%>).css("backgroundColor","black").css("color","white");
```